# Constructor of the same name as recursive data type

Tags: haskell

I am trying to achieve simple switch function for learning purposes:

As far as I went was:

```
Prelude> data Case a b = Case a b (Case a b) | Default deriving Show
Prelude> let switch Default = Nothing
Prelude> let switch u (Case x y z) = if (x == y) then y else (switch u z)
```

And it should behave like

```
switch 2 Case 1 2 $ Case 2 3 $ Case 3 4 $ Default
```

returns 3

```
switch 6 Case 1 2 $ Case 2 3 $ Case 3 4 $ Default
```

returns Nothing

When I try to invoke it though i get:

```
Prelude> switch 1 (Case 1 2 Default)
*** Exception: <interactive>:11:5-30: Non-exhaustive patterns in function switch
```

I'm wondering if by using (Case a b) Haskell will get to understand that a b are type bearers not value. Is there possible without aliasing the time for

```
data Casy a b = Case a b (Casy a b) | Default deriving Show
```

to get this example to work?

Comment: Your issue is just that GHCi doesn't expect multi-line definitions unless you use one of the features mentioned in the suggested question. Alternatively, if you load the definitions from a source file they will work just fine.

Comment: Additionally, you probably meant `u == x` rather than `x == y`.